# Using Cauchy-Condensation Test to prove convergence of product series

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

Revising for an exam and can't seem to answer this question.
Let $\sum^\infty a_n$ converge, and let $\{b_n\}$ be a decreasing, convergent sequence. Using the Cauchy Condensation Test, Prove that $\sum^\infty a_n b_n$ converges

Comment: due - https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Abel%27s_test - the sum converges.

 


Hint: prove that $$\sum {a_n}{b_n} < \infty  \iff \sum {2^n}{a_{2n}}{b_{2n}} < \infty $$

Comment: according to Abel test,  $\sum a_{n}b_{n}$ must converges. 

$\sum {a_n}{b_n} < \infty \iff \sum 2^{n} {a_{2n}}{b_{2n}} < \infty $ 

therefore - you'd have to prove the other direction. 
supposing $\sum {a_n}{b_n} < \infty$ (as follows from Abel test), 

prove that: 

$$\sum 2^{n} {a_{2n}}{b_{2n}} < \infty $$.